# PHP shorthand for combination of ?? and ?: operators?

Tags: php, operator-keyword, shorthand

is there any "beautiful" shorthand in PHP to use ?? and ?: operators together?

I often check something for array keys to exist and to "evalutate to TRUE" in web apps, e.g. for ids, such as

```
if ($foo['id']) {
    // ...
}
```

but this leads to PHP notices starting with PHP 8.x+.

I could write

```
if (isset($foo['id']) && $foo['id']) {
    // ...
}
```

but this makes the code such unreadable.

An alternative would be

```
if ($foo['id'] ?? NULL) {
    // ...
}
```

but also this is ...cruel.

Especially when writing something like

```
echo 'Rsource foo '.(($foo['id'] ?? NULL) ? 'edit' : 'create');
```

Any ideas, recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

> array keys to exist and to "evalutate to TRUE"

That's [`empty`](https://www.php.net/empty), or rather, `!empty`:

```
if (!empty($foo['id']))
```